# upload_max_filesize increase ignored by phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, php

I menaged to decrease [upload_max_filesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) (to 127M from default 128M), but I am unable to increase it (I tried 129M). What may be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I increased also memory_limit, post_max_size what fixed this problem.